# How to handle with return number given by lua_resume?

Tags: lua, coroutine, lua-api

I have some coroutine handling code like this:

```
int coro_re_num = 0;
int coro_state = lua_resume( coro_lua, master_lua, narg, &coro_re_num);

if ( coro_state == LUA_OK)
{
    // do something
}
else if ( coro_state == LUA_YIELD)
{
    // do_something
}
else
{
    const char* err = lua_tostring(coro_lua, -1);
    log_error(err);
}

lua_pop(master_lua, coro_re_num);
```

When coroutine ends with `OK` or `YIELD`, it works properly. But when it ends with any error, the last `lua_pop` always fail, and I noticed the `coro_re_num` is relatively large (mostly more than 10) which causes stack underflow by `lua_pop`.

What does the `coro_re_num` means when the coroutine ends with error? How to handle it?

Comment: You're popping from the wrong stack in `lua_pop(master_lua, coro_re_num);`